# httr POST error: "invalid charachter '-' in numeric literal"

Tags: r, influxdb, httr, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I am new to Influx and R and I am trying to query data from InfluxDB 1.8.4 (with Flux enabled) in R Studio. I can't figure out what's wrong with my **code**:

```
dburl <- "http://localhost:8086/api/v2/query"

influxquery <- sprintf(
  'from(bucket: "plcview/autogen")
    |> range(start: 2017-06-27T04:16:58.278Z, stop: now())
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "MONITORING")
    |> map(fn:(r) => ({ r with _time: uint(v:r._time) }))'
)

httr::POST(url=dburl,
           add_headers('Content-Type: application/vnd.flux',
                       'Accept: application/csv',
                       'Accept-Encoding: application/gzip'),
           body=list(q=influxquery))
```

The **data** I am trying to get looks like this:

```
time                     MONITORING equipmentNumber workplace
----                     ---------- --------------- ---------
2017-06-27T02:16:58.599Z 1          L4212M1017      3
2017-06-27T02:16:58.6Z   1          L4212M1017      4
2017-06-27T02:16:58.6Z   1          L4212M1017      1
2017-06-27T02:16:58.6Z   1          L4212M1017      2
2017-06-27T02:17:03.14Z  0          L4212M1017      1
2017-06-27T02:17:03.14Z  0          L4212M1017      2
2017-06-27T02:17:03.14Z  0          L4212M1017      4
2017-06-27T02:17:20.007Z 1          L4212M1017      1
2017-06-27T02:17:36.988Z 1          L4212M1017      4
2017-06-27T02:17:36.988Z 1          L4212M1017      2
```

I always get this **error message**:

```
Response [http://localhost:8086/api/v2/query]
  Date: 2021-04-08 14:19
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 53 B
{"error":"invalid character '-' in numeric literal"}
```

I can push the same request through (with all those parameters) using Postman. Why doesn't it work in R?
Is it maybe a problem with the way R stores the data? I thought it could be the Timestamp form my time series data in rfc339 format (which has '-' to separate the dates.

Any ideas? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Since I am sending a database query as raw text but there is not parameter for this in the `httr::POST` function, you need to add the `content_type()` parameter. This makes sure that the query can be understood. It is specifying what is comming next, in the body of the POST-request.

Here my code:

```
my_raw_result <- httr::POST(url=dburl,
                            add_headers('Content-Type: application/vnd.flux',
                                        'Accept: application/csv',
                                        'Accept-Encoding: gzip'),
                            content_type("application/vnd.flux"),
                            body=influxquery)
```

You also do not have to add the `q` as a key to your `influxquery` in the body of the request. This is only the case if you are trying to query data from InfluxDB v1x using InfluxQL instead of Flux